# Does UWP mail app support Simple MAPI Function call from desktop app?

Tags: email, uwp, mapi

Is there any good way to launch UWP mail app through [MAPISendMail function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296721(v=vs.85).aspx) with **file attachments** from desktop app?
`mailto:` protocol will launch but it doesn't attach files...

---

Update 2022-12-06:

To access Windows Runtime API from .NET Framework app, check: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps - Windows apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)

Edit csproj and add `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And also add `Windows` reference. `HintPath` is mandatory and its important file `Windows.winmd` is included in Windows 10 SDK.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Windows">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.19041.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And code:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp76
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\filepath").AsTask().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile(file));
        }
    }
}
```

A sharing token will be retrieved in string.

```
7808B122-02DD-4996-A22D-C1D9EEC880E4
```

Comment: Self note: store app may not support MAPI implementation `DLLPath`. Prepare dummy mail app entry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail` and set it to `HKCU\Software\Clients\Mail` manually, if user decides to use built-in Windows 10 mail app.

Comment: hey, I'm curious, how did you resolve it? Can you post an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:
mailto:?ms-attachments=*token1,token2,...*

Whereas the tokens have been created with SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile() for the respective files you want to attach.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.SharedStorageAccessManager

Note that not all email clients support this format, but the built-in Windows 10 Mail app does support it.

Comment: Thank you for response! My colleague tested `SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile() `, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Hey, Stefan, I'm curious, can you somehow obtain that token from a WinForms or C++ desktop process?